# python: recursive function not returning true or false

Tags: python, recursion

I have implemented i unbalanced binary tree i python, and would now like to make a searching method for it that can return True and False.
However, i have now made this recursive function, which works in terms of printing results, but it only returns 'None'.

I'm guessing that this is because it is only the last recursive call that returns something, and the outer ones do not.

How do i fix this? i feel that this should be fairly trivial, i bothers me that i am so lost.

```
def traverseSearch(self, ID, current):

    if current == None: # if we have not found our goal, the current node is null
        print("not found")
        return False

    if current.ID == ID: # succes statement
        print("found")
        return True
    if ID > current.ID: # call recursive on left children if data is bigger
        self.traverseSearch(ID, current.rightChild)

    if ID < current.ID: # call recursive on Right children if data is bigger
        self.traverseSearch(ID, current.leftChild)
```

it is now changed to the following, but still seems to return nonetype

```
def traverseSearch(self, ID, current):

    if current == None: # if we have not found our goal, the current node is null
        print("not found")
        return False

    if current.ID == ID: # succes statement
        print("found")
        return True
    if ID > current.ID: # call recursive on left children if data is bigger
        self.traverseSearch(ID, current.rightChild)

    if ID < current.ID: # call recursive on Right children if data is bigger
        self.traverseSearch(ID, current.leftChild)
```

Answer (score 3):

Your guess was correct; you just need to return the results of the recursive calls.

```
        return self.traverseSearch(ID, current.Child)
```

Don't worry; we all get lost on something that is obvious in hindsight at some point.

Comment: hmm.. it still seems to return None-type

Comment: never mind :D im being stupid, i was using another method to acces the recursion which was void. lol

Comment: Such a good answer. However, I am still confused with what on earth does this return self.traver... do